# Android Studio 2.0 builds are really slow

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm experiencing very slow and resource-intensive builds on Android Studio 2.0 stable...

Sometimes I get to "Instant run", and yes it's very quick.
But all others builds are 3 times longer than before.

Anyone experiencing the same thing ?

Comment: Which version of the gradle are you using ?

Comment: Gradle plugin : 2.0.0, gradle wrapper : 2.10

Comment: Yeah, exactly as I am, and yes, I'm also having really long build times in my emulator

Comment: Same here. I tried to tweak the gradle.properties file, still no luck.

Comment: Yes, same here. I  m working on a multidex app and the build sometimes is 10 times longer :(

Comment: I am the same - it's painfully slow. When it does load the subsequent builds are quite fast.

Comment: Why question is closed. It very very slow. On Android Studio 2.0 I am able to run app only 2 times in an hour. It only building, building and building.....

Comment: Finally I shifted back to Android Studio 1.3.0. Its very bad and that IDE is hell slow